# How to populate dropdown list from ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a form with 2 dropdown list + 1 hidden field.

First dropdown list is city.

Second dropdown list is district values based on selected city above.

The hidden field will be shown on or off based on particular district value using Jquery.

**My problem is:**

In the city dropdown list, I have onchange ajax function which help to generate values in the district dropdown list. However, When a particular district value is selected, the hidden field won't show up.

**Here is my html form:**

```
<form>
<select id='main-cat' name='maincat' onchange="sortSubcat(this.value)"/>
<option value="">Please select one category</option>
<option value="City 1">City 1</option>
<option value="City 2">City 2</option>
<option value="City 3">City 3</option>
</select>
<select id='subcat' name='subcat'>
<option value=''>Please select a district</option>
</select>   
<div id='morefield' style='display:none'>
 <input type='text' name='option1'/>
</div>
</form>
```

**Here is the onchange ajax function:**

```
function sortSubcat(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/member/sortsubcat.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Here is my part of Jquery code to trigger the hidden field if a particular disctrict value is selected:**

```
$("#subcat").change(function(){
if ($(this).val() == 'district a'){ 
    $("#morefield").css("display","block"); 
}else{
    $("#morefield").hide();
}
});
```

**Here is my php file:**

```
<?php
 require_once("../configs/dbconnect.php");
 if (!empty($_GET['q'])){
 $q = basename($_GET['q']);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE maincat=:q";
 $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $result->bindParam(':q', $q);
 $result->execute();
 echo "<option value=''>Please select a district</option>";

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
    echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";  
 }
 }
 else{
 echo "<option value=''>Please select a district</option>";
 }
 $conn=null;
 ?>
```

Comment: can we have an example of what that `sortsubcat.php` file returns?

Comment: your code works as you are describing.  if you have CSS on the page as well, you may need to look at it or check the `value` attributes of the `option` elements in that district `select`

Comment: @Deryck: this coding is working. However, after I selected a city, I saw list of disctricts appeared in the dropdown list, I viewed page source, the option lists were not shown there? I thought, this maybe the problem that a particular city value is selected, the hidden field would show up as expected. But I don't know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: when you "view source" it shows you the initial code the browser is given from the server.  So any dynamically created or changed elements won't appear.  You can see these with "inspect element"

Comment: @Deryck: Do you think this may be the issue that Jquery can't pick up the selected value from disctrict dropdown list? Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your actual problem anymore after that question.  Is the issue that clicking the populated option in the second dropdown is not showing your hidden input?  **Or** is your second dropdown not being populated the way you want?  If you take your code and put an example `<option value="district a">Example</option>` in the district select, and then select it, your input field reveals itself .

Comment: @Deryck: in my jquery, when I select a value: disctrict a, the hidden input field should show up. However, it did not. However, if I hard code the value in the district dropdown list (don't need the onchange ajax function just yet), then it shows up the hidden input field.

Comment: In that case, try this `$(document).on("change", "#subcat", function() {...})` instead of `$("#subcat").change(...);`

Comment: @Deryck: I updated my code to yours. However, I still would not show the hidden input field. It does not show any error in firebug, so I don't know what i should look for to fix it.

Comment: posted as answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

try this below line

`console.log($(this).val());` after line `$("#subcat").change(function(){`

Now find what value your are getting on changing the dropdown which was loaded from ajax in console.

Comment: I opened console log in firefox (Ctrl + Shift +J) and to change value in city. But I dont see anything show up in console log window?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle  ?   html and javascript . PHP not needed. hardcode the options for now .

Comment: i dont think so. Because this only works with a php file because ajax send request to a php file and get response from it. I don't know how to imply php file in jsfiddle?

Comment: Response from ajax show list of district option. Which is correct. However, Jquery can't pick up the selected district value. It only pick up the value if I hardcode the district values in the html form.

Comment: Somhow, jquery can't pickup values dynamically generated by ajax response.'

Comment: after showing the dropdown in browser,  right click on the dropdown and inspect element. Again in `debugger` right click on select element and copy that to fiddle and add js code . that's all.

Comment: It will works in jsfiddle because when i manually assign options to the disctrict dropdown list (copy response from ajax), it works perfectly. But the problem is that, options generated from ajax response jquery can't regconise it so that It can't trigger to show the hidden input field.

Comment: here is response from ajax: <option value=''>Please select a district</option><option value='district a'>District A</option><option value='district b'>District B</option><option value='district c'>District C</option>.

Comment: where you are appending this response to select box ? i mean dropdown.

Comment: When i add this response to the district dropdown list (i hardcode it, without onchange event from ajax), the jquery can recognise it and trigger on the hidden input field.

Comment: If I do like this, it will work:<select id='main-cat' name='maincat'/>
<option value="">Please select one category</option>
<option value="City 1">City 1</option>
<option value="City 2">City 2</option>
<option value="City 3">City 3</option>
</select>
<select id='subcat' name='subcat'>
<option value=''>Please select a district</option><option value='district a'>District A</option><option value='district b'>District B</option><option value='district c'>District C</option>
</select>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87342/discussion-between-j-santosh-and-giang-nguyen).

Comment: I left out this onchange="sortSubcat(this.value)" on the city dropdown list and hardcode district dropdown list as above. It works.